# How to auto select the state from an option list when using address autofill

Tags: html, autofill, street-address

I made an form in HTML and the autofill feature on Chrome successfully fills in the street address, city, and zip. If I leave the "state" input with `type="text"`, then it gets autofilled successfully as well. However, if I use a `select/option` dropdown list, then it does not get autofilled.

For the options, I tried using state abbreviations for the value like:

```
<label>
    <select>
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <select>
    State
</label>
```

and I tried using the state name for the value:

```
<option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
<option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
```

And neither one works.

Is there a way to get Google Chrome's autofill to automatically select a state from a dropdown list when it is auto-filling the address?

Notes:

- I'm interested in getting it to work for any other
  browsers/extensions that auto fill addresses for users, but I've only
  tested in Chrome.
- a javascript solution would be acceptable, but it's not what I'm wanting. But, no jquery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<select autocomplete="state">
```

will work too

Comment: [`address-level1`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete#Values) and not of `state` seems to be correct now. tried in chrome, worked.

Answer (score 2):

Embarassingly enough, 10 seconds after I posted this question, I realized that I didn't set the `name` on the `select`.

So, I changed it to:

```
<select name="state">
    <option ...>
<select>
```

and it works now, whether using the abbreviations or the full state name